# How to import an Eclipse project from Windows to Mac OS

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, macos

I am trying to import an Eclipse project from Windows to the Mac, but Eclipse does not recognize the folder as a project folder.

Looking at the folder in the Mac OS Finder, all I see is `pom.xml`, with no sign of `.project`

Comment: ensure m2e is installed, then import->maven->existing maven project

Comment: In the folder you are bringing over, is there a .project file in there?

Comment: Files starting with `.` files are hidden in Mac OS X. The file should be there.

Comment: Project folder in windows have .project, but this file not is shown in mac os, and eclipse not recognize the folder as a project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS is probably hiding the folder. You can either disable file hiding by entering

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

into terminal and then using force quit to restart finder, or you can use eclipse to export your project to something like a .jar file and save yourself the headache.

Good luck